# i am unable to reallocate memory to integer using realloc in c

Tags: c, realloc

I am trying to re-allocate 20 bytes to an integer that already occupies 10 bytes using this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{
        int *ptr;
        ptr=(int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
        printf("size before re-allocation : %d bytes",sizeof(ptr));

        ptr=(int *)realloc(ptr,20*sizeof(int));
        printf("size after re-allocation : %d bytes",sizeof(ptr));
        free(ptr);
}
```

but the output is showing 8 bytes before realloc and after realloc too.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot programmatically check how much memory is allocated for something in C, at least, there aren't any standard functions that can do it. You (the programmer) must keep track of it and must make sure all allocated memory has been properly deallocated using `free`

Comment: `sizeof` is a **compile-time** operator. You cannot use it in order to retrieve a **runtime** piece of information (which in your example, is the size of the allocated memory block returned by `malloc` and `realloc`).

Comment: Also, 1) `void main()` → `int main(void)` 2) Remove casts from `malloc` and `realloc` 3) Use `%zu` instead of `%d` because `sizeof` returns `size_t`, not `int` 4) Check if `malloc` and `realloc` were successful by looking at their return values.

Comment: @barakmanos In that case, what about `sizeof(VLA)`, sir? Sorry if i'm missing something very basic.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: If I were to guess, then I'd say that any compiler supporting VLA must be replacing the non-compilable expression `sizeof(arr[n])` with the compilable expression `sizeof(*arr)*n`, which can be evaluated during runtime.

Comment: @barakmanos - [There's no need to guess, we have a standard draft publicly available](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p2). "Evaluated" in that paragraph means exactly what you guessed at.

Comment: `ptr=(int *)realloc(ptr,20*sizeof(int));` is dangerous. What happens if this returns `NULL`? You'll lose access to original pointer. Better to use `void *temp = realloc(ptr,.......); if (temp != NULL) { ptr = temp;} else { /* handle error */ }`.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Guess I should start implementing compilers then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(ptr)` determines the size of a single integer pointer. `sizeof` is an operator that is applied statically during translation (except for variable length arrays, but it's not the case here). The static type of `ptr` is `int*`, so you get `sizeof(int*)` printed.

`sizeof(ptr)` will never be `sizeof(int[10])` because arrays are not pointers, despite many tutorials erroneously teaching they are.

The good news however, is that if `malloc`/`realloc` return any address other than NULL, you do indeed have `ptr` point to memory that can contain 10/20 integers. So you just need to keep track of the allocated size.

Note however, that `malloc` and its kin do memory allocation during the run-time of your program, in opposition to `sizeof` that (for the most part, VLA's again) returns a result way before your program is even run.

Comment: I'd use 'compilation' instead of 'translation', and I would add that `malloc`/`realloc` "do their thing" during runtime, in order to emphasize and distinguish between the two cases. Although OP's technical misunderstanding is about the usage of `sizeof`, I think that the real insight that he or she is missing, is the difference between compile-time and runtime.

Comment: @barakmanos - Translation is the term used by the standard, and I try to adhere to that. The other point is indeed good, thanks.